# Where is namespace `i` defined

Tags: v8

I am studying the source of the V8 engine. There is a namespace named `i`, which I guess should be an alias of `v8::internal`, but I could not find where it (or the alias) is defined.

I have grepped the whole source tree using `namespace i`, or `using i =`, but I could not find anything.

As shown in the following code snippet:

```
    if (!context.IsEmpty()) {
      i::Handle<i::Context> env = Utils::OpenHandle(*context);
      i::HandleScopeImplementer* impl = isolate->handle_scope_implementer();
......
```

as shown https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/api/api.cc#L277

Could anyone who is familiar with the code base tell me where it is defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be found at the end of [globals.h](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/2ae8888a5a0a186b78099d9824530033b6dc9a9a/src/common/globals.h#L1537):

```
namespace i = v8::internal;
```